# How to print the closest 2D point to the origin in c in this situation?

Tags: c, algorithm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge_sort(int a[], int n)
{
int *tmp_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
internal_msort(a, n, tmp_array);
free(tmp_array);
}
void internal_msort(int a[], int n, int helper_array[])
{
int left = n / 2, right = n – left;
if (n < 2)
return;
internal_msort(a, left, helper_array);
internal_msort(a + left, right, helper_array);
merge(a, left, a + left, right, helper_array);
memcpy(a, helper_array, n * sizeof(int));
 }

int main()
{
int N;
printf("Enter number of points: ");
scanf("%d",&N);
printf("\n");
int points[N][2];
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    printf("Enter point: ");
    scanf("%d, %d",&points[i][1],&points[i][2]);
    printf("\n");
}

int squares_of_distances_array[N];

for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
{
  int squares_of_distances_array[j] = (points[j][1]*points[j][1]) + (points[j][1]*points[j][1]);   
}

merge_sort(squares_of_distances_array[], int N);
.
.
.
```

My code so far.I need to write a code in which prints 2D points (x,y) sorted by 
their distance from the origin (0,0).My question here is after I use the "merge_sort" function to sort the array "squares_of_distances_array" that contains the square of each distance
of every 2D point (x,y) from the origin in my 2D points array "points[N][2]" ,How do I use
the sorted array "squares_of_distances_array" to print the points from the point that is the closest to the origin to the point that has the biggest distance from the origin.

I will provide an example, for the points (4,4) (1,6) (2,5) :-

squared distance of (4,4) = 4^2 +4^2 = 32

squared distance of (2,5) =  2^2 +5^2 = 29

squared distance of (1,6) = 1^2 +6^2 = 37

so "squares_of_distances_array" after the merge sorting will look like this

squares_of_distances_array={29,32,37} and according to this form of the array we will print the points in the following order :- (2,5) (4,4) (1,6).

Thx for any help

Answer (score 0):

Your `merge_sort` function has to also sort the corresponding indices and return an array of the sorted indices. Something like:

```
merge_sort(squares_of_distances_array[], squares_of_distances_indices[], int N);
```

The returned array would look like

```
squares_of_distances_indices = {1,0,2}
```

Then use that sorted index array to print the coordinates.

Comment: How can I create a function to remember the sorted array indexes?

Comment: You can use the C [qsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qsort) function as an example. You'll need to create a comparator function. The link provides an example and there are many more online.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a structure like

```
struct points {
    int x, y, distance;
};
```

and a array of structure pointers. Then allocate and populate the structures. Then sort the **pointers to structures** according to their corresponding dist property. You'll then have the points sorted according to their distance from origin.

```
struct points *mypoints[size];
for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
  mypoints[i] = malloc(sizeof (struct points));
  populate(mypoints[i]); // assign with x, y, dist
}
sort(mypoints);
```